# Leaflet sidebar not opening on load

Tags: plugins, leaflet, cartodb

I'm using the [leaflet-sidebarv2](https://github.com/Turbo87/sidebar-v2) plugin to create a sidebar for a cartodb/leaflet map. I'm running into problems that I a.) can't get the options to work – close button, autoPan, etc) and b.) can't use setContent to dynamically set data.

The sidebar functions as expected. The problem is modifying it seems to have no effect. I also get an error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" on the `setTimeout` and `setContent` lines.

```
      cartodb.createLayer(map, {
      user_name: {{user_name}},
      type: 'cartodb',
      sublayers: [{
         sql: 'select * from {{table_name}}',
         cartocss: '#layer',
         interactivity: 'cartodb_id, name',
         auto_bound: true
      }]
    })
    .addTo(map)
    .done(function(layer) {
      var barData;

      barData = layer.createSubLayer({
        sql: 'select * from {{table_name}}',
        cartocss: '#layer {marker-fill: #bababa; marker-opacity: 0.3; marker-width: 4px; }',
        interactivity: 'name, location'
      });

      //on click
      barData.on('featureClick', function(e, pos, pixel, data) {
        //log active data
      console.log("Name: " + data.name + " @ " + data.location);
        $('#map').css('cursor', 'pointer');
      });

      barData.setInteraction(true);

      //hover pop-up
      var infobox = new cdb.geo.ui.InfoBox({
        width: 100,
        layer: layer,
        template: '<p class="cartodb-infobox">{{name}}</p></br><p>{{location}}</p>',
        position: 'top|right' // top, bottom, left and right are available
      });

      $("body").append(infobox.render().el);

      // leaflet-sidebar> closeButton not engaging
      var sidebar = L.control.sidebar('sidebar', {closeButton: true});
      map.addControl(sidebar);

      //content not showing up anywhere
      sidebar.setContent('test <b>test</b> test');

     // sidebar still collapsed at reload
     setTimeout(function () {
         sidebar.show();
    }, 500);

      });
  }      
  window.onload = main;
```

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong? I've got all the right pieces loaded in the head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using the wrong API. The `setContent()` method and the `options` hash is part of the [leaflet-sidebar](https://github.com/Turbo87/leaflet-sidebar) library API, but not of [sidebar-v2](https://github.com/Turbo87/sidebar-v2).

Comment: Ah. Thank you! Well that makes sense. And there are no options for v2?

Comment: not yet. since there are two different APIs for the v2 (leaflet and jquery) it is a bit more difficult.